# Remove symbol when crawling data using scrapy

Tags: python, regex, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to get text by scrapy from a website. This is sample code:

```
def parse(self, response):
        for kamusset in response.css("div#d1"):
            text = kamusset.css("div b::text").extract()
            print(dict(text=text))
```

This is the result:
[image]

I want to remove the '.' symbol and every number symbol. So, I use regular expression. I change my code:

```
def parse(self, response):
        for kamusset in response.css("div#d1"):
            text = kamusset.css("div b::text").re(r'[a-z]+')
            print(dict(text=text))
```

But the result is:[image]

I don't expect the result like that. I want to get like this:

{'text': ['abadi', 'mengabadi', 'mengabadikan', 'pengabadian', 'keabadian']}. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse from `text` you scraped with `re`:

```
import re
text = ['aba.di','meng.a.ba.di','megn.a.ba.di.kan','1','2','peng.a.ba.di.an','ke.a.ba.di.an','1','2']
stack = [re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]+', '', e) for e in text]
text_new = [i for i in stack if i!=""]
print(text_new)
```

text_new will be:

```
['abadi', 'mengabadi', 'megnabadikan', 'pengabadian', 'keabadian']
```